# Linker does not point out errors; multiple definition warnings pointed to the same line

Tags: c++, linker, multiple-definition-error

Believe me, I've been through several posts on here, but none of them addressed the issue I'm having. I have this 2-year-old program that used to run. I'm kind of reviving it, but for some reason now it does not run.

Clearly, I'm having multiple definitions (too many of them):

============================ TERMINAL OUTPUT =============================

```
build_files/LinkedStack.o: In function `LinkedStack':
/home/owner/workspace/opencv-galaxies/utilities/structures/LinkedStack.cpp:12: multiple definition of `LinkedStack::LinkedStack()'
build_files/LinkedStack.o:/home/owner/workspace/opencv-galaxies/utilities/structures/LinkedStack.cpp:12: first defined here
```

... and so on, and so forth, ... and it all ends with:

```
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [executables/Assignment3.out] Error 1
```

========================================================================

Strangely, the linker does not indicate any errors throughout the extensive list of warnings, not to mention that these aren't true multiple definitions. Note that each warning in a "multiple...-first defined... " pair refers to the same line. Now I don't know what to do.

I'm wondering if it has something to do with the rather busy syntax of our makefile (though it looks really good to me):

=============================== MAKEFILE =================================

```
CFLAGS = -g -Wno-deprecated

OBJECTS = utilities/basic/image.h build_files/image.o build_files/ReadImage.o build_files/ReadImageHeader.o build_files/WriteImage.o build_files/LinkedStack.o build_files/unsortedList.o build_files/region.o build_files/Main.o

executables/Assignment3.out: $(OBJECTS)
    g++ $(OBJECTS) -o executables/Assignment3.out build_files/*.o $(CFLAGS) -lncurses
```

...

```
build_files/LinkedStack.o:  utilities/structures/LinkedStack.h utilities/structures/LinkedStack.cpp
    g++ -c $(CFLAGS) utilities/structures/LinkedStack.cpp -o build_files/LinkedStack.o
```

...

```
clean:
            rm build_files/*.o executables/Assignment3.out
```

=========================================================================

So, these are my questions: 1) why did the linker see an error and 2) why am I having so many multiple definitions?

If you want a clarification, let me know even if you kind of have an idea of what's going on.

============================== CODE EXAMPLE ==============================

Here's the full example function (I don't want to make this too long):

```
//constructor
LinkedStack::LinkedStack()
{
    topPtr = NULL; //set top pointer to null
}
```

========================================================================

Comment: narrow it down and post the stripped-down version of the code - leave the class with 1 method.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore : Should I do the same with makefile?

Comment: Those _are_ errors, not warnings (even though it doesn't say “_error_: multiple definition ...”). Now, please imagine yourself being another SO user (like me), wouldn't you like to see some _actual code_ (C++ code) to be able to help? (see also http://sscce.org/) Because for now the best we can do is blind guesses (like, “you aren't including a .cpp file in a header, are you?”)...

Comment: @gx_ : I'm sorry; I just thought what I gave would be enough. Anyway, the post is updated. And to answer you question, no; it's the header file that is included in the .cpp file, i.e. `#include "LinkedStack.h"` in the .cpp file.

Comment: @gx_: I don't think that's a blind guess. I think that's a fact.

Comment: @DietmarKühl Well, generally when I can only see error messages but no code I personally feel kind of “blind” so the best I can do is trying to “guess” :) (maybe I should have used “I” instead of “we” in my previous comment, but that seemed “common sense” to me). _Edit:_ I see that you have posted an answer, that starts with “most likely”, which I think illustrates my point ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely you are including a header which implements methods non-inline in multiple translation units. The Makefile has nothing to with it. You'll need to find the definition of the methods and see how they end up being included into multiple files. If they are actually in a header file the easiest fix is probably to make them all `inline`.

The compiler doesn't see that you are including the header into multiple translation units as it always only processes one at a time. When the linker sees the various object files, it just see many definitions of the same thing and complains. I would have thought that the linker pointer at the location of the definition, though.

Comment: Thanks. I see that my partner has made some unwarranted silly changes like including both the .h and .cpp of one class into the .h of another class. This might be the cause.

Answer (score 0):

Given the info you provided, it is hard to even guess what the problem is. However, make sure that
 a) you do not include any cpp file in another cpp/h file. 
 b) any implementation you define in h file, is inline-ed.
(I would guess b is your problem)

Comment: What else would you suggest I should include in order to make your job easier on this one? Because I'm looking at [sscce](http://www.sscce.org), and the answer isn't all that obvious to me.

Comment: Did you check the two things I mentioned?

Comment: As I've commented on Dietmar's answer, there is certainly (a), unnecessary inclusions, but not (b), no inline functions implemented ... yet.

Comment: In your answer to Dietmar, you said that your partner included cpp of one class to h file of another. Unless I didnt understand you, this is your problem! the cpp will be compiled in each translation unit that include that h file, causing multiple definition.